# how to set input status checked on hover only via Css?

Tags: html, css, hover

how I can set input status checked on hover only via Css?
Actually is the setting on click but i need it on hover, how I can do that?

here is the example

Comment: here is the example  https://jsfiddle.net/stoyan33/f45y1qew/

Comment: Please add the link to the question itself.

Comment: With CSS... **this is not possible!**

Comment: What is your understanding of `input status`?You can trigger something on hover in CSS, but it's not going change any status afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Well not possible...with css you can't create a environment in which radio input be checked on hover because in css you can style the elements but you cannot fire any event.

You have to use little JS to achieve it.

Here is the code

```
$('input').on('hover', function(){
  $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

> Above code will trigger click on hover of same element.

Comment: I need solution in pure css over selectors, not over Jquery
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: i already mentioned in my answer brother that its not at all possible with css..i just gave you the js solution in case you need it because js is the only option for this and you do not have to ask one more question...